# jsoup - strip all formatting and link tags, keep text only

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Let's say i have a html fragment like this:

```
<p> <span> foo </span> <em> bar <a> foobar </a> baz </em> </p>
```

What i want to extract from that is:

```
foo bar foobar baz
```

So my question is: how can i strip all the wrapping tags from a html and get only the text in the same order as it is in the html?
As you can see in the title, i want to use jsoup for the parsing.

Example for accented html (note the 'á' character):

```
<p><strong>Tarthatatlan biztonsági viszonyok</strong></p>
<p><strong>Tarthatatlan biztonsági viszonyok</strong></p>
```

What i want:

```
Tarthatatlan biztonsági viszonyok
Tarthatatlan biztonsági viszonyok
```

This html is not static, generally i just want every text of a generic html fragment in decoded human readable form, width line breaks.

Comment: Have you tried [`fragment.text()`](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)?

Comment: The first time I see Hungarian text in a question.  :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**With Jsoup:**

```
final String html = "<p> <span> foo </span> <em> bar <a> foobar </a> baz </em> </p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

System.out.println(doc.text());
```

**Output:**

```
foo bar foobar baz
```

If you want only the text of p-tag, use this instead of `doc.text()`:

```
doc.select("p").text();
```

... or only body:

```
doc.body().text();
```

---

### Linebreak:

```
final String html = "<p><strong>Tarthatatlan biztonsági viszonyok</strong></p>"
        + "<p><strong>Tarthatatlan biztonsági viszonyok</strong></p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

for( Element element : doc.select("p") )
{
    System.out.println(element.text());
    // eg. you can use a StringBuilder and append lines here ...
}
```

**Output:**

```
Tarthatatlan biztonsági viszonyok  
Tarthatatlan biztonsági viszonyok
```

Comment: Thanks! Now i face another problem: line breaks. It can be solved by a new TextNode(elem.html(), "").getWholeText(), but it makes my special accent characters to html encoded ones. How can i get the decoded human readable characters?

Comment: Can you post some example html (what html you have and what you need as result) and/or Code.

Comment: Thanks! That's what i also figured out, but it guess there is a smarter method somewhere. It'll be good for now.

Answer (score 15):

**Using Regex**: -

```
String str = "<p> <span> foo </span> <em> bar <a> foobar </a> baz </em> </p>";
str = str.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

*OUTPUT*: -

```
  foo   bar  foobar  baz
```

**Using Jsoup**: -

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str); 
String text = doc.text();
```

Comment: Do not use regex for HTML parsing: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 9):

Actually, the correct way to clean with Jsoup is through a [Safelist](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Safelist.html)

```
...
final String html = "<p> <span> foo </span> <em> bar <a> foobar </a> baz </em> </p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Safelist wl = Safelist.none()
String cleanText = Jsoup.clean(doc.html(), wl)
```

If you want to still preserve some tags:

```
Safelist wl = new Safelist().relaxed().removeTags("a")
```

Comment: is there a reason not to use the static methods i.e. Jsoup.clean(html, WhiteList.none())?

Comment: Small fix,  you can't initialize the `Jsoup` class, you need to use `Jsoup.clean(html, wl)` (You need to pass the HTML string, not the document)