# Strip tags from generated XML file

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a Java class which returns statuses of particular systems, this then returns a new ResponseEntity and generates an XML file from it. I want to strip the XML tags from the file and display just the content.

Java:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public ResponseEntity<StatusData> getStatus() throws IOException {
        StatusData status = new StatusData();   
        status.setIsDbUp(statusService.isDbUp());
        status.setIsAppUp(statusService.isAppUp());
        return new ResponseEntity<StatusData>(status, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Generated XML:

```
   <com.ck.app.StatusData>
       <isDbUp>DB: UP</isDbUp>
       <isAppUp>APP: UP</isAppUp>
   </com.ck.app.StatusData>
```

I wrote an XSL script but am unsure how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this for examples on how to run an XSLt from within Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used jsoup before to do this with html, I am sure it will work for your xml also

http://jsoup.org

Here is an example

[jsoup - strip all formatting and link tags, keep text only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943734/jsoup-strip-all-formatting-and-link-tags-keep-text-only)

Answer (score 0):

Look this for strip xml tags and show only a content:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

Answer (score 0):

You can recur through the DOM tree nodes and print the text nodes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException, JAXBException, URISyntaxException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException, NoSuchMethodException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.xml"));

    visit(doc);
}

public static void visit(Node node) {
    NodeList nl = node.getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

        Node child = nl.item(i);
        if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
            System.out.println(child.getTextContent());

        visit(child);
    }
}
```