# Get text without tags from web page using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have to extract some data from a web page using Jsoup.

I have easily extracted the data contained in tags, but I still need some data which is not tagged.

This is an example of the HTML source :

```
<a id="aId" href="aLink" style="aStyle">
    <span id="spanId1">
        <b>Caldan Therapeutics</b> 
        Announces Key Appointments And A Collaboration With 
        <b>Sygnature Discovery</b>  
    </span>
    <span id="spanId2" style="spanStyle2">
        5/17/2016
    </span>
</a>
```

I have already extracted the data contained in `<b>` tags as well as the date but what I want now is to extract the sentence `Announces Key Appointments And A Collaboration With`.

As you can see, this sentence has no tags.

What can I do to extract it ?

I have already done my research and all I could find was how to strip all the tags out.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943734/jsoup-strip-all-formatting-and-link-tags-keep-text-only

Comment: I have already seen that one and all it does is to strip the html tags out. It is not what I want. What I want is to extract only the untagged sentence `Announces Key Appointments And A Collaboration With`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found an anwser to that specific need and I would like to share it with anyone who might face the same issue in the future.

All you can do is use the function `ownText()`, it exclueds the text from the element's children tags.

In our example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://source-url").get();
    Elements spanTags = doc.getElementsByTag("span");
    for (Element spanTag : spanTags) {
        String text = spanTag.ownText();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark this as answer. Answer and marking your answer are not considered bad on StackOverflow. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using the following code, but it will return your text as a String, replace paragraphs with "\n" and will not allow you to detect text styles (like bold, italics, and so on).

If you only want to get the plain text, this is really useful:

```
Element aElem = doc.getElementById("spanId1");
String yourText = aElem.wholeText();
```

If in your case you use `aId`as the ID for the element, you'll also get the content of `spanId2` and will not be able to easily tell what part of your text is a date.